# How to position an element within a table cell?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move the "X" to the right, but whenever I change the padding in the style, the table is resized. What is the way to shift the "X" to the right side without messing with the table width?

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style>
.hash {
    font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.keywords {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 42px;
    background: yellow;
}
</style>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
    <div class="about">
        <table width="580" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="intro">
            <tr>
                <td width="72" height="40" class="hash">X</td>
                <td width="508" align="left" valign="middle" class="keywords">aaa / bbb / ccc</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: text-align:right ?

Comment: Yes, but I need fine, pixel-by-pixel control. Let's say, I would like to move the "X" with 20 px to the right side.

Comment: text-indent:20px ?

Comment: Still, that shifts the cell's width to the right side. I would like to have the yellow and green cells at fixed width and just shifting the "X" around.

Comment: text-indent will not change the width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use text-indent. remove overflow:hidden and set max-width. also you can add text-indent to keywords. I created an example.

```css
.hash {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  text-indent: 80px;
  max-width: 60px;
}

.keywords {
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 42px;
  background: yellow;
  text-indent: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <table width="580" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="intro">
    <tr>
      <td width="72" height="40" class="hash">X</td>
      <td width="508" align="left" valign="middle" class="keywords">aaa / bbb / ccc</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If I set the `text-indent: 80px;` the will still result in the green cell expanding to the right side, shrinking the yellow cell. -- Is there a way to absolutely lock the width of the green cell and the yellow cell, and just shift the elements within those cells to left or right?